# In Visual Assist X in Visual Studio 2013, how to expand/display the previously closed "Find References Results" pane?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-assist, visual-assist-x

I frequently encounter a minor, but annoying, UI issue with `Visual Assist X` in the `Visual Studio 2013` development environment.

Often, after executing a `Find References` command using VAX, I close the *Find References Results* pane by clicking its *X* close box, in order to make more room for the main editor.

Sometimes I want to re-open the pane *without* re-executing the `Find References` search.  In other words, the search is complete - I just want to re-display the pane with the results.

I have hunted meticulously through every menu, both `Visual Studio`'s *View* menu, and the `Visual Assist X` menu.  I cannot find any way to re-display the *Find References Results* pane.

Here are two screenshots that show the issue.

---

**Before screenshot: "*Find References Results*" tab is displayed**

[image: Find References pane is displayed]

---

**After screenshot: "*Find References Results*" tab is hidden**

[image: Find References pane is hidden]

How do I re-display `Visual Assist X`'s *Find References Results* pane within `Visual Studio 2013` without re-executing the `Find References` command?

(I know it's a small detail, but it's a nagging annoyance.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option **does** exist in the `Visual Assist X` menu - but, unintuitively, it is under the `Tools` sub-option in the menu.

So, to re-display `Visual Assist X`'s *Find References Results* pane (when it is hidden), go to `VASSISTX` -> `Tools` -> `Find References Results`.

[image: Resolved]